# Ordering by a OneToOne self-referencing field in Django

Tags: django, one-to-one

I'm trying to order a query by a self-referencing OneToOne field. The model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    prior_foo = models.OneToOneField('self', related_name='following_foo', null=True, blank=True)
```

There is no guarantee that the pk for the linked item is higher or lower, (or any other field is useful besides the OneToOne reference) e.g.:

Foo.pk  |  prior_foo.pk

- 3      |    null
- 6      |      3
- 5      |      6
- 10     |      5

I'd love to have the query return:
[foo_3, foo_6, foo_5, foo_10]

Comment: [foo_3, foo_6, foo_5, foo_10]? How did you get this order? What is it based on?

Comment: Thanks @evergreen. In the table I'm trying to show the foo objects with primary keys of [3, 6, 5, 10] are referring to prior_foo of [null, 3, 6, 5] respectively. One specific example, `foo.pk == 6` has `foo.prior_foo.pk == 3`. Therefore in the query ordering, I'd like `foo.pk == 6` to immediately follow `foo.pk == 3`.

Comment: Take a look at the the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428149/ordered-lists-in-django). It's several years old, but still applies. Reading a linked list in the correct order from a database is very inefficient.

Comment: Thanks @evergreen, that's a good answer. After thinking about it further, I think I may be able to engineer my way around using the self-referencing OneToOne. If you want to post your comment as the answer, I'll accept it!